# Prefixing sub-folder names to a filename, and moving file to current directory

Tags: linux, shell

I have a car stereo that reads USB sticks, but the stereo's "random" function only works on one folder, so I want to move all files to a parent folder, "STICK/music", but to have the Artist, and Album if any, added to the filename.
But what I've done is sort of hard-coded, and I'd like to be able to use different sticks.
I would like to have these ("RHYTHMBLUES" is the name of the stick):

```
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist/Album/name1.mp3
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist/Album/name2.mp3
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist/name3.mp3
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist/name4.mp3
```

renamed with folder names and moved to "music":

```
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist-Album-name1.mp3
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist-Album-name2.mp3
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist-name3.mp3
/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/Artist-name4.mp3
```

I thought of having a bash command to call "doit":

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\" ; /home/homer/doit \"{}\" " \;
```

and "doit" would contain:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
echo --------------------------------
pwd
for i in *.mp3
  do new=$(printf "${1}/${i}")
  # remove the ./ at the beginning of the name
  new=`echo "${new}" | cut -c 3-`
  # replace folder separators
  new=`echo "${new}" | tr '/' '-'`
  echo "$i" "/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/$new"
  mv -T "$i" "/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/$new"
done
```

Comment: In which directory do you plan to issue the _bash command_?

Comment: Probably in /media/homer/STICKNAME/music/, but willing to listen to suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**doitbaby.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

moveTo () { # $1=directory, $2=path, $3=targetName
    local path="$(realpath "$1")"
    for file in "$path"/*; do
        if [ -d "$file" -a -n "$3" ]; then
            moveTo "$file" "$2" "$3""${file##*/}"-
        elif [ -d "$file" ]; then
            moveTo "$file" "$path" "${file##*/}"-
        elif [ -f "$file" -a "${file##*.}" = 'mp3' ]; then
            echo 'FROM: '"$file"
            echo 'TO  : '"$2"/"$3""${file##*/}"
            # mv "$file" "$2"/"$3""${file##*/}" # Uncomment this for real usage.
        fi
    done
}
removeEmptyDirs () {
    local path="$(realpath "$1")"
    for file in "$path"/*; do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            rm -fR "$file"
        fi
    done
}
moveTo "$1"
# removeEmptyDirs "$1" # Uncomment this for real usage.
```

**Note**
I have commented 2 lines in the above script. Test it first before any further real actions.

Call the script like this: (Make sure the path is correct. This is the expected path by this script by the way.)

```
./doitbaby.sh '/media/homer/RHYTHMBLUES/music/'
```

Comment: Thank-you. Will test this arvo.

Comment: Wow, thanks Darkman.  I had not thought to use recursion: well done.
Works like  a dream.

Comment: One final note, the remove empty directories function that I've used for a long time is:

`find . -type d -empty -print -delete`

Comment: @Alfredo Good for you. Your's is certainly better and safer than mine.